# Jquery Tag It plugin - new line for each tag when they should float next to each other

Tags: jquery, tags

Im using the "tag it" plugin. Everything working fine, except for each time a tag is added to the holder, a new is taken. Has anyone experienced this?

Thanks

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it

http://levycarneiro.com/2010/03/tag-it-tag-suggestions-editor-and-autocomplete-in-a-jquery-ui-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be a CSS problem, make sure that you have the following:

```
ul.tagit li { 
    display: block;
    float: left;
    ...
}
```